# Reading a parameter value of module instance in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have an ALU module with a set of parameters used as opcodes.

```
         parameter ADD=0,
         SUB = 1,
         MUL = 2,
         DIV = 3;
```

Currently building a testbench for that module, I just want to read these values in the testbench, something like C language `alu.ADD` .

Is that possible ?

Comment: Have you tried simply `instanceName.ADD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any variable within a hierarchy, including parameters, in Verilog testbenches pretty much exactly as you have shown.

```
instanceName.variableName
```

Say you instantiated your module and called the instance `alu`, then you could access the value of the parameter `ADD` in that instance by simply accessing:

```
alu.ADD
```

---

You can even do multi-level. Say your `alu` instance instantiated something called `adder`, which had a signal called `cout`. You could access that with:

```
alu.adder.cout
```

Comment: I tried that before and didn't work !! I use `iverilog` and when it fails it prints `I gave up` 

I've just tried it now and it worked...